# AWS Transcription and Content Redaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

wondered if someone could help.

I am using the PHP AWS SDK, v3 (just updated to latest), it's working as it should, can send MP3, returns a json file with transcription.

However, I want to use Content Redaction, but no matter what I try I can't see to get it to work, I don't get any errors, my code looks like this:

```
$transcribe->startTranscriptionJob([
    'ContentRedaction' => [
        'RedactionType' => 'PII',
        'RedactionOutput' => 'redacted'
    ],
    'LanguageCode' => 'lang',
    'Media' => [
        'MediaFileUri' => 'someurl',
    ],
    'MediaFormat' => 'file',
    'OutputBucketName' => 'bucket_name',
    'Settings' => [
        'ChannelIdentification' => true,
        'SplitChannelTranscription' => true,
    ],
    'TranscriptionJobName' => 'output_filename' 
]);
```

I don't get any errors, it just transcribes it without the Content Redaction.

From their docs:

"To enable content redaction using the API, complete the request parameters of the ContentRedaction object in the StartTranscriptionJob operation. See the request syntax for the StartTranscriptionJob action for more information. To see if content redaction has been enabled for a particular transcription job, use GetTranscriptionJob. To see which jobs have content redaction enabled, use ListTranscriptionJobs."

Comment: Did you try submitting the job via the AWS Transcribe management console, to verify that redaction is working? I just created a recording, uploaded it to S3 and ran it through Transcribe with redaction activated. The output file correctly redacted content. So, try it in the console, and if that works, try the **exact same configuration** via the SDK, and let us know what you find!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I did try the management console and it does work, I only selected 'Audio Identification -> Channel identification'  and selected ' Automatic Content Redaction'  - which I believe matches my above code?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - should I also mention I am using us-east-1 as the region?

Comment: Could you run "ListTranscriptionJobs" after you create one via the SDK and verify it has the ContentRedaction set appropriate in the response?  Perhaps compare it to a job that you created via the AWS console where redaction actually worked.  That would confirm that AWS was at least receiving that part of your request successfully.